# How to run jester in Apache server

Tags: nim-lang, jester

I want to use jester in production server.
However jester can run only in terminal.app with sync running.
I want to know how to run jester asynchronous like php-pfm.

I wrote this code:

```
import jester, asyncdispatch, json

routes:
  get "/":
    resp "Hello World!"

  get "/users/@id":
    var data = %*{"id": @"id"}
    resp $data, "application/json"

runForever()
```

And now, I run this code:

```
nim c -r cgi.nim
```

How can I run this behind an Apache server?

Comment: Is running Apache as a reverse proxy before jester not good enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you compiled (with `nim c -r cgi.nim`) you should have an executable called `cgi`. You have to launch this on the background, maybe using something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Then you configure Apache to [ReverseProxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/reverse_proxy.html) towards your `cgi` nim program, that is listening at http://127.0.0.1:5000 by default.

Here you have a complete tutorial using systemd+watchdog instead of supervisor, and nginx instead of Apache: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/wiki/Tutorial:-Creating-a-(micro)-service

Comment: I'll set like your answer!